# Any way to know if a cluster exists in orientdb?

Tags: orientdb

Is there a command/query to know if a cluster exist in the DB? or to know the list of clusters in the DB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Document API**:

```
// if you know the name of the cluster
db.existsCluster("V");
// if you only know the id of the cluster
db.existsCluster(db.getClusterNameById(9));
```

Using **Graph API**:

```
graph.getRawGraph().existsCluster("V");
graph.getRawGraph().existsCluster(graph.getRawGraph().getClusterNameById(9));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the API docs:

```
  To view all clusters, from the console run the CLUSTERS command:

  CLUSTERS:
  -------------+------+-----------+-----------+
  NAME        | ID   | TYPE      | RECORDS   |
  -------------+------+-----------+-----------+
  account     | 11   | PHYSICAL  |      1107 |
  actor       | 91   | PHYSICAL  |         3 |
  address     | 19   | PHYSICAL  |       166 |
  animal      | 17   | PHYSICAL  |         0 |
  animalrace  | 16   | PHYSICAL  |         2 |
  ....        | .... | ....      |      .... |
  -------------+------+-----------+-----------+
  TOTAL                                23481 |
  --------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: (If by chance you meant to specify "from the Java API" - the answer is the same, but you will send an OCommand to the ODatabase instead of sending a command string to the console stdin)

Comment: I need to get this information either query or executing a command agains the server, not by using the console.

In any case , running the command CLUSTERS give me this error:

com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.CLUSTERS